# Tortoise SVN merge adds `<<<<<<< .working`

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I'm merging trunk into my branch to keep it up to date, but the process adds `<<<<<<< .working` (and other, similar metadata) within the files themselves - I've been getting a large number of tree errors but I've made some extensive changes so it's to be expected (although it seems like the merge is flagging every single folder as a tree conflict)

Is there any way to prevent Tortoise SVN from adding this metadata to the file directly (that messes about with its ability to compile) and/or cleaning a large number of files without having to revert + re-merge?

APPEND: The answers so far are *correct* however, the problem here is that metadata was remaining *after* resolving the conflict. Could this just be a bug?

Comment: Um - fix the merge conflicts?

Comment: That's the thing, they remain after I've resolved the conflicts.

Comment: Do you save the file after resolving?

Comment: Indeed, it's incredibly strange. The Resolved list is empty despite numerous files obviously requiring resolution.

Comment: Did you mark the conflicts as Resolved?

Comment: @alroc yes I did. Even after reverting and re-merging and re-resolving all the conflicts this is still occurring within many of my source files.

Comment: For solving the problem I mean not adding this extra lines. Which works very badly with semanticdiff tool

Answer (score 7):

These markers are inserted when tortoise can't resolve merge conflicts automatically, so it marks those as conflicted with information from both files - working copy and repository. These markers will be removed after you resolve conflicts in any way - manually with TortoiseMerge, with menu items "resolve conflicts use mine"/resolve conflicts use theirs". But you **have to** decide what part will be used in your working copy after update.

Comment: I suspected they are in some way unresolved conflicts however I have already resolved them and none appear in the list, which is what is foxing me.

Comment: if you resolved them with TortoiseMerge, have you pressed toolbar button "mark as resolved" after saving it?

Comment: Yes. To be honest I've just reverted and am going through the merge process again, since something obviously anomalous occurred.

Answer (score 5):

Those [`<<<<<<<` markers](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html) are added by Subversion itself (it isn't a TortoiseSVN feature) but as far as I know not for *tree* conflicts. You must have regular file conflicts.

As far as I know, TortoiseSVN doesn't have any feature to fully automate conflict resolution. Options I can think of:

- Choose "Prefer local" or "Prefer repository" every time the "Resolve Conflict" shows up.
- Choose "Resolve all later" (I believe you only need to do it once) and, once finished merging, use the "Check for modifications" dialogue to select all conflicts and choose a method from the context menu.

Answer (score 4):

this occurs when we run merge and conflicts comes in same file more than once.

Comment: Subversion actually stops a merge if there's a conflict when merging one of multiple revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Those metadata are written by SVN because of conflicts. You can solve using this command:

```
svn resolved <directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If SVN does not support "merge tracking", you might get the same conflicts every time you repeat your merge. Make sure that "merge tracking" is available.

see: [How do I use the new SVN merge-tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173974/how-do-i-use-the-new-svn-merge-tracking)